# Looking for a good Visual C++ 2010 compatible JSON parser that supports JsonPath for windows 32/64 bit platform. Any recommendation?

Tags: json, parsing, visual-c++, jsonpath

Have looked at quite a few like the following:

https://rapidjson.org/index.html - Supports VC++ 2010. But, not sure about JsonPATH
https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons - Supports JsonPATH. But, not sure about VC++ 2010

Answer (score 0):

The best resource I can think of right now is the [JSON Path Comparison project](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/).  It groups by language/framework, so finding what you need should be fairly easy.